# Move Text with Mouse on Razor PartialView

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

This forum is flooded with questions that handle this problem in Windows Forms, but I'd like to know the workings of this mechanic using MVC (Razor).

I have a partial view which (or should) serves as a drawing canvas. This drawing canvas will only hold text controls. A user gives his input in the input field and POST submits it. The text is then correctly displayed on the partial view.

[Image displays canvas and the textarea inside that I want to move](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICVJE.png)

Now I'd like to drag the text around my canvas by mouse clicking it. In the future I'd also want to save the position, into the Position property in TextModel, to where it was dragged. This might limit the amount of solutions.

How do I do this? I understand how people add the mouse event to the form code-behind for Windows Forms. But I'm not sure how I can add such events to the ViewController in MVC, if that's even the way to do it.

Thanks for your help/advice in advance.

**Text.cshtml (Index)**

```
@using TestMySmartPhotobook.Models;
@model TestMySmartPhotobook.Models.TextModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Tekst</title>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div id="designer-canvas" class="col-md-4">
            <div id="PartialTextCanvas" style="width:200px; height:200px;">
                @{ Html.RenderPartial("PartialTextCanvas", Model); }
            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="content-builder" class="col-md-4">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("AddText", "Text", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "ValidationForm", name = "ValidationForm" }))
            {
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Text)
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Text, new { @id = "TextInput", @placeholder = "Text here." })

                <input type="submit" id="placeTxtBtn" value="Place Text" />
            }

        </div>


    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/LoadPartialCanvas")
</body>
</html>
```

**PartialTextCanvas.cshtml**

```
@using TestMySmartPhotobook.Models;
@model TestMySmartPhotobook.Models.TextModel
<h1>Text Partial</h1>
<div id="bookCanvas">
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Text, new { id = "tb", name="tb" } )

</div>
```

**TextController.cs**

```
// GET: Tekst
public ActionResult Text()
{
    return View(new TextModel());
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddText(TextModel model)
{
    return PartialView("PartialTextCanvas", model);
}
```

**TextModel.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using TestMySmartPhotobook.Domain;

namespace TestMySmartPhotobook.Models
{
    public class TextModel
    {
        public string Text
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public Color TextColor
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public int Size
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public int Height
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public Tilt Tilt
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public Position Position
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public Font Font
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use a jQuery plugin such as[jQuery-ui draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/)

Comment: Thanks, I've got it working!